# What is the verb that describes the process of forming an interpretation?

Tags: logic

"Formal Semantics", "The Semantics of Logic" and "Model-Theoretic Semantics" are names for the process of forming interpretations, but I am looking for a verb that describes what I am doing when I study a set of sentences and form an interpretation that holds for those sentences.

e.g. If someone is 'running', it is easy to form a conception of what that person is doing. So what I am after is a verb that describes the process of applying Model-Theoretic Semantics to form an interpretation.

e.g. I do not want to say "I am Model-Theoretic Semanticing", and I do not want to say, in a long-winded way, "I am applying Model-Theoretic Semantics to formulate an interpretation". I am looking for a simpler verb, like 'interpretation-forming' for example.

I would appreciate it if anyone knows of such a verb, and I would like to also posit that if no such verb exists, then where over 100 years has past since Principia Mathematica was released, it is probably about time that logic has such a word.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Ummm.... "interpreting"?

Comment: Maybe 'observing'?

Comment: Whatever you say. I'd avoid the use of the word "semantics", as it has been over-used (at least in computer science) to the point where it has more or less lost all meaning (which is quite surprising as it means "meaning"!).

Comment: Hi Dean, I like your approach..."observing an interpretation". For instance if I have a set of sentences of which could either apply to a FOL under finite model theory or operate over an infinite model, then when I "observe" the later, that's the interpretation I acknowledge/form-in-my-mind/choose. I'll go with that nomenclature for now. Thank you, much appreciated.